# What is the max value for node ids in overpass?

Tags: overpass-api

I wanted to use overpass with custom data using the .osm format.

Overpass does not consider negative node IDs, so I added a prefix, staying <63 bits.

ex. : node id = "540000000000001" (in the .osm file)

But I have this error when I want to import data :

```
Reading XML file ... finished reading nodes. Flushing to database
..terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
./bin/init_osm3s.sh: line 44:  2007 Broken pipe
bunzip2 < $PLANET_FILE 2008 Aborted
(core dumped) | $EXEC_DIR/bin/update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR/$META $COMPRESSION
```

If I delete a few zeros, it works (ex. : node id = 9900000000001).

I've read that de value of node ids must be encoded in 64bits (signed). It seems that overpass allows less. What is its max value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no explicit max value except for the 64 bit limit. However, the current implementation needs too much main memory to handle very large node ids.

I have created a bug report here: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/465

Comment: Thank you for the report. Ive noticed the performance issue with large node ids too.